# I want to update mysql table after successful redirection

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, sql-update

I am trying to make a php website. I need help for that. I am creating a url shortner and I need to update total views of links. I want to UPDATE mysql db after successful redirection.

for eg,

I am visiting a link abc.in/ggl which will redirect me to google site. Total views of the link is 20. If anyone else will go to link abc.in/ggl and it will redirect after 2 seconds to google site. If redirection is successful then my mysql db will be updated and total views of google website will be 21 in my database. If redirection is not successful then my mysql db will not be updated and total views of google site will be 20.

my codes are these and its not working.

```
$a = header( "refresh:5;url=$rd" );

        if ($a)
        {
        $query="UPDATE `url` SET `view`=(`view`+1) WHERE code = 'ggl'";
        $mysql1 = mysql_query($query);
        }
```

$rd comes from database and in this case it is google site.

Comment: `header()` doesn't return a value, so `if ($a)` will evaluate to false and won't execute. In any case, your argument to `header()` doesn't look like an HTTP header. Does this work at all?

Answer (score 0):

Using queue? You throw task in queue before you redirect user, after that worker is processing this task.